# Get list of printers with Adobe Flex

Tags: apache-flex, printing, air, adobe, flash-builder

Documentation for flash.printing.printjob says there should be a printers() method.  Using Flashbuilder 4.6 the IDE code complete says it doesn't exist.

I'm using Flash SDK 4.6, targeting a desktop environment.

Anyone know if (and when) they pulled this method from the library?

Comment: Do you mean you're using Flash SDK 4.6?  What type of project are you creating?  ( AIR / Web / Mobile )?  Per the docs; the printers property--it isn't a method--is only available on AIR desktop projects.  It won't be available on mobile devices or browser based projects.  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/printing/PrintJob.html#printers

Answer (score 0):

[`PrintJob.printers`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/printing/PrintJob.html#printers) is a static readonly property only available in the AIR runtime, supported only on desktop operating systems.  There is no support for mobile or AIR for TV devices.

> Provides a list of the available printers as String name values. The
>   list is not precalculated; it is generated when the function is
>   called. If no printers are available or if the system does not support
>   printing, the value is null. If the system supports printing but is
>   not capable of returning a list of printers, the value is a Vector
>   with a single element (its length property is 1). In that case, the
>   single element is the actual printer name or a default name if the
>   current printer name cannot be determined.

Test for support by calling [`PrintJob.isSupported`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/printing/PrintJob.html#isSupported), such as:

```
if (PrintJob.isSupported)
    var printers:Vector.<String> = PrintJob.printers;
```

Tracing the printers vector for me outputs:

> RICOH Aficio MP C5502
>   Canon MP210 series

Comment: That does work.  Thank you.  I thought it was a method so I was using printers();

Now that I have the list, can I set the printer to use programattically?  By changing the printjob.printers property, I would guess?